# Java - Find Object Group with Maximum Value

Tags: java, stream, average

I have a list of cars for sale and I need to find the car make that has the highest average price. The car class looks like the following pseudocode:

```
class Car 
{
    string make;
    string model;
    double price;
}
```

So for example, if I had the following collection of cars:

- **Make**: Honda       **Model**: Civic    **Price**: €8000
- **Make**: Honda       **Model**: Jazz      **Price**: €6000
- **Make**: Skoda       **Model**: Fabia     **Price**: €7500

Then obviously it should return that Skoda is the car make with the highest average price.

I want to do this using streams, however I'm a bit stumped as to where to start. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorting collections/streams is extensively documented, there are many questions about it here, and many tutorials out there. Please understand that this isn't a free tutoring service where people write down the same information every time someone comes asking for it. So: do some research first. Pick up a good tutorial, look at that code, and then apply it to your problem. And then, when you have a specific problem, write up a [mcve] and we will gladly help with that.

Comment: @GhostCat You have clearly not bothered to properly read what I'm asking because the question you linked to mine is not related. I am NOT asking to find an object in a list with a maximum property, it is more complex than that! And I have read done research, the reason I am asking this question in the first place is because I am stumped and don't know how to continue. And FYI It's really frustrating receiving a patronising comment like this, I fully understand how Stackoverflow works.